# Change the ordering of NULL values in all table columns postgresql call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using rails with postgresql to populate a dataTable and was wondering if there is a way to change the default behaviour of NULLS being the higher value (coming after large numbers when sorted) to become equivalent to lower than 0 in a sort. From what I understand this is a built in postgresql behaviour, so I think I will have to use the sql call to achieve this. And I need to apply this to all columns so it works with the DataTables sort ASC/DESC functionality.

Example some functionality similar to:

```
  def get_raw_records
     Analytics::Database.where(id: 7).order('give nulls < 0 value here for all columns?')
  end
```

NULLS FIRST/ LAST does not give this functionality I need something like coalesce that ideally does not return a sorted instance but changes the default behaviour of nulls placed after large values when for it is sorted client side

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
order by coalesce(col_name,-1)
```

Comment: This will put the NULLS to the first rows even with changes to ASC/DESC on the column, I am looking to change the sequence when sorting so they always are smaller than 0

Comment: @VaoTsun. From the question it is observed that the intention is  just to consider null as lower than 0.

Comment: yes, but OP asks for all columns, so it might be not even an integer?..

Answer (score 0):

close to Sabari suggested:

```
db=# with c(v) as (values('1'),('a'),(null),(null),('b'))
select * from c
order by coalesce(v,'-infinity') asc;
 v
---


 1
 a
 b
(5 rows)

db=# with c(v) as (values('1'),('a'),(null),(null),('b'))
select * from c
order by coalesce(v,'-infinity') desc;
 v
---
 b
 a
 1


(5 rows)
```

instead of fixed integer below zero I use `-inf` here. which works fine with `text` (not because `text` understands `infinity`, but rather because `-` goes before `[a-z]` or `[0-9]`), but would not work with normal `integer`. Of course you can cast it to `float`:

```
db=# with c(v) as (values(1::float),(3),(null),(null),(-9))
select * from c
order by coalesce(v,'-infinity') desc;
 v
----
  3
  1
 -9


(5 rows)

db=# with c(v) as (values(1::float),(3),(null),(null),(-9))
select * from c
order by coalesce(v,'-infinity') asc;
 v
----


 -9
  1
  3
(5 rows)
```

with is dangerous (well, not in sorting though) itself (and ugly). which leads to the answer - I don't see good solution here from the top of my head... You should better make separate boundaries for different data types.

Comment: Nice I see what you are doing here am looking now for the syntax to make it work with all columns similar to your function above. Now I have  ```.order("COALESCE(column, -1)")``` works to return that specific column sorted correctly (though it unfortunately breaks the datatable ASC/DESC functionality :( ...)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can specify in the order by clause how you want NULL sorted:

```
select 1 as col UNION select 2 UNION SELECT NULL ORDER BY col ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

You can either specify NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html